# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 in postman java springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The application after I run it runs normally there is no error, but after I try to use Postman it appears Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080. The server port setting in my applicationProperties is 8080, XAMPP has been turned on but still an error. I've tried removing Postman and XAMPP and reinstalling them but I still get the same errors.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/product-categories
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 28c3391d-ae3f-4031-aa24-d43ecd2e2bf4
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Request Body
```

```ini
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kadaiden
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.santiang:demo-kadaiden >---------------------
[INFO] Building demo-kadaiden 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                   
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ demo-kadaiden >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Air\Latihan Spring Boot\demo-kadaiden\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ demo-kadaiden <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:run (default-cli) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.1)


2023-12-31T14:02:42.030+07:00  INFO 9648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2023-12-31T14:02:42.043+07:00  INFO 9648 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-31T14:02:42.043+07:00  INFO 9648 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.17]
2023-12-31T14:02:42.103+07:00  INFO 9648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-31T14:02:42.105+07:00  INFO 9648 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1423 ms
2023-12-31T14:02:42.244+07:00  INFO 9648 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-12-31T14:02:42.306+07:00  INFO 9648 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final

2023-12-31T14:02:43.859+07:00  WARN 9648 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling 
refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryMasterController' defined in file [D:\Air\
Latihan Spring Boot\demo-kadaiden\target\classes\com\santiang\demokadaiden\controller\ProductCategoryMasterController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through cons
tructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryMasterImpl' defined in file [D:\Air\Latihan Spring Boot\demo-kadaiden\target\classes\com\santiang\demoka
daiden\service\impl\ProductCategoryMasterImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryRepos
itory' defined in com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositori
esConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository.findAllByOrderName(); Reason: Fai
led to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository.findAllByOrderName(); No property 'orderName' 
found for type 'ProductCategory'
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-31T14:02:43.906+07:00 ERROR 9648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryMasterController' defined in file [D:\Air\Latihan Spring Bo
ot\demo-kadaiden\target\classes\com\santiang\demokadaiden\controller\ProductCategoryMasterController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter
 0: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryMasterImpl' defined in file [D:\Air\Latihan Spring Boot\demo-kadaiden\target\classes\com\santiang\demokadaiden\service\im
pl\ProductCategoryMasterImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryRepository' defined in
 com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: 
Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository.findAllByOrderName(); Reason: Failed to create que
ry for method public abstract java.util.List com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository.findAllByOrderName(); No property 'orderName' found for type 'P
roductCategory'
        at ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryMasterImpl' defined in file [D:\Air\Latihan Spri
ng Boot\demo-kadaiden\target\classes\com\santiang\demokadaiden\service\impl\ProductCategoryMasterImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor paramete
r 0: Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryRepository' defined in com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories 
declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.Pro
ductCategoryRepository.findAllByOrderName(); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryR
epository.findAllByOrderName(); No property 'orderName' found for type 'ProductCategory'
        at 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.666 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-31T14:02:44+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS D:\Air\Latihan Spring Boot\demo-kadaiden> mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.santiang:demo-kadaiden >---------------------
[INFO] Building demo-kadaiden 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ demo-kadaiden >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-kadaiden ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Air\Latihan Spring Boot\demo-kadaiden\src\test\resources
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ProductCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public ProductCategory(Long id, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Spring Boot won't start, because Spring Data JPA cannot generate a query because, as the error says _"No property 'orderName' found for type 'ProductCategory'"_. In other words, show your `ProductCategory` class.

Comment: And contrary to your claims, your application does not _"run normally there is no error"_. The logging of Spring Boot clearly shows errors, and also _"Application run failed"_, so it terminated and is not listening on port 8080.

Comment: What should I do, so that my application can run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that (currently) prevents Spring Boot from starting is:

> Error creating bean with name 'productCategoryRepository' defined in
> com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository defined
> in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositori esConfiguration: Could
> not create query for public abstract java.util.List
> com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository.findAllByOrderName();
> Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract
> java.util.List
> com.santiang.demokadaiden.repository.ProductCategoryRepository.findAllByOrderName();
> No property 'orderName' found for type 'ProductCategory'

The problem is that `ProductCategoryRepository` has a method called `findAllByOrderName()`, but `ProductCategory` does not have a property called `orderName`. It does have a property `name`, which is probably what you need to use. So, to solve this, define the method in `ProductCategoryRepository` as `findAllByName()`.